# Poly-time reduction: D and D Comp

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, decision-problem

Looking at the Independent Set problem and its complement, I want to show that IS is poly-time reducible to its complement, however I am struggling on coming up with the reduction function.

I will define its complement for further clarity, does every subset such that its size is at least $k$ in $V$ contain at least one edge between its vertices? My intuition is below.
$$f(G, k) = (G, i-k),$$
where $i = |V|$?

Comment: It should help if you clarify what exactly you mean with the complement of IS. What problem do you mean precisely? Are you building a reduction to vertex cover, or to deciding the non-existence of an independent set, or something else?

Comment: IS = Independent Set Decision Problem. I am referring to Independent Set's complement. (The complement of this problem).  Given a decision problem X, its complement X Complement is the collection of all instances s such that s is not in X. No I want to show that independent set is poly-time reducible to it's complement.

Comment: @Juho The complement of a decision problem is completely standard.

Comment: Are you still confused about the relationship between [vertex cover and independent set](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40808/relationship-between-independent-set-and-vertex-cover)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independent set and its complement are **NP**-complete and **co-NP**-complete, respectively. If you found a polynomial-time reduction between those two problems, you'd have proven that **NP$\,=\,$co-NP**, resolving one of the biggest open problems in theoretical CS.

Comment: Ah okay! What if on top of this, Independent set and its complement are NP-complete and co-NP-complete, respectively. If you found a polynomial-time reduction between those two problems, and Independent Set is NP-complete which it is, what would possibly be the strongest claim to be made? would it be the same?

Comment: What do you mean "What if on top of this, [IS] and its complement are NP-complete and co-NP-complete, respectively"? That's not a what-if: it's a statement of fact. And it's not "on top of" what I said: it's exactly what I said.

Comment: My apologies didn't read it carefully. Thanks.